# Try to find all linear transformation satisfy $\mathscr{A}(AB) = \mathscr{A}(B)\mathscr{A}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V = \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$. Find all $\mathscr{A} \in \text{End}(V)$ such that for any $A, B \in V$, we have $\mathscr{A}(AB) = \mathscr{A}(B)\mathscr{A}(A)$.

I am able to identify the transpose transformation and the zero transformation as the solutions to this problem, but I am unable to find a proper way to prove it.

Comment: This condition also holds for maps of the form $\mathscr A(X) = PX^\top P^{-1}$ for some invertible $P \in \Bbb F^{n \times n}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ satisfies the condition and let $\mathscr{B}=\mathscr{A}\circ(-)^T$. Then
$$\mathscr{B}(AB)=\mathscr{B}(A)\,\mathscr{B}(B)$$
so $\mathscr{B}$ is an *algebra* endomorphism of $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$. It's well known that the only nonzero algebra endomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ are inner automorphisms (see references below). So there is $P\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ invertible with $\mathscr{B}=P(-)P^{-1}$ and hence $\mathscr{A}=P(-)^TP^{-1}$.

**References:**

- Greub, W. *Linear Algebra*, 4th ed. problem V.1.16 or problem XIII.4.2.
- Greub, W. *Multilinear Algebra*, 2nd ed. subsection 1.30.

Comment: Thank you very much！

Comment: @GeorgeLin You're welcome! By the way on this site you're encouraged to upvote any answers you find helpful and also accept one you feel is most relevant. This rewards the contributors and removes the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\ker(\mathscr{A})$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$. Hence it can only be $0$ or the entire $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$.

If it is $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ then $\mathscr{A}\equiv 0$ and we are done. Assume $\ker(\mathscr{A})=0$. Hence $\mathscr{A}$ is an isomorphism.

Consider $L_B,R_B\in End(V)$ as $L_B(X)=BX$ and $R_B(X)=XB$, where $B\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$.

Notice that

- The kernel of $L_B$ consists of those matrices whose columns belong to the Kernel of $B$. Thus, $\dim(\ker(L_B))=n\dim(\ker(B))$.
- The kernel of $R_B$ consists of those matrices whose rows belong to the Kernel of $B^t$. Thus, $\dim(\ker(R_B))=n\dim(\ker(B^t))=n\dim(\ker(B))$.

Since $XA=\mathscr{A}^{-1}(\mathscr{A}(A)\mathscr{A}(X))$, we have  $R_{A}=\mathscr{A}^{-1}\circ L_{\mathscr{A}(A)}\circ\mathscr{A}$.

Therefore, $$n\dim(\ker(A))=\dim(\ker(R_A))=\dim(\ker(L_{\mathscr{A}(A)}))=n\dim(\ker(\mathscr{A}(A))).$$

So $\dim(\ker(A))=\dim(\ker(\mathscr{A}(A)))$, which means that $\mathscr{A}$ is a rank preserver.

By [theorem 1 in page 64](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/732742504BB86D9E38834774A7496B94/S0008414X00002996a.pdf/linear-transformations-on-algebras-of-matrices.pdf), $\mathscr{A}(X)$ can only be $\mathscr{A}(X)=UXV$ or $\mathscr{A}(X)=UX^tV$, where $U,V$ are invertible matrices.

Since $\mathscr{A}(Id)=\mathscr{A}(Id.Id)=\mathscr{A}(Id)\mathscr{A}(Id)$ and the fact that $\mathscr{A}(Id)$ is invertible (since $Id$ is invertible), we have  $\mathscr{A}(Id)=Id$. So $V=U^{-1}$ in both cases.

Now $\mathscr{A}(X)=UXU^{-1}$ cannot be true, since it would imply that $\mathscr{A}(XY)=\mathscr{A}(X)\mathscr{A}(Y)$. By hypothesis we would obtain

$$\mathscr{A}(Y)\mathscr{A}(X)=\mathscr{A}(XY)=\mathscr{A}(X)\mathscr{A}(Y).$$

Since $\mathscr{A}$ is surjective, this equation implies that matrix product is commutative. Absurd.

Comment: Thank you very much!Considering from the perspective of the kernel space is something I hadn't thought of.